# What is diffrence bwtween JSONResponse and JSONRenderer in Django

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

All I know is that JSONResponse is HttpResponse with content_type="application/JSON"
And JSONRenderer will convert the python dictionary data to JSON format 
Do they do the same work? Or is there any difference between them.

I've read the difference between JSONParser and JSONRenderer which doesn't really solve my problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between JSONParser and JSONRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669322/difference-between-jsonparser-and-jsonrenderer)

Answer (score 1):

JSONResponse and JSONRenderer are quite similar and perform largely the same action. Both format server responses in JSON, however their usage differs.

Both convert plain Python data to JSON format through the use of `json.dumps` and send the output back to the client. See [JSONRenderer source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/renderers.py) and [JSONResponse source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/response.py) for the code.

In terms of their difference, a JSONResponse should be returned by a view method in generic Django to send data with the header `Content-Type: application/json`. JSONRenderer on the other hand is used in Django Rest Framework to format serialized data to JSON format depending on the `accept` header in the received request. Check the documentation on Django request-responses: (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/) or the docs on DRF renderers (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/) for more on their usage.

As an example a JSONResponse might be used like this:

```
def some_view(request):
    data = get_data()
    return JSONResponse(data)
```

And usage for JSONRenderer in `settings.py`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer', 'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer'
    )
}
```

The above will render response data for routes using Django Rest Framework in JSON depending on the `accept` header of the request.